# Master report not getting generated after integrating all subreports

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, subreports

I have 4 subreports that I am trying to integrate in master report.

- First subreport has 7 pages
- Second has 2 pages
- Third has 2 pages
- Fourth has 2 pages

The sizes of each of the jasper files are respectively:

- 131 kB
- 58 kB
- 85 kB
- 174 kB

The contents of all the subreports are mostly static text.

---

The problem that I am facing is when I am integrating these subreports with a master report and previewing it in Excel format

- the iReport tool (4.1.3 version) stops functioning
- after much elapse time(about 10 mins) it gives following error message

  ```
  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space null
  ```

Could you please tell me what could be the reason?
I have tried all options. I also tried setting the first subreport as master report, but i still face the same problem.
I would really appreciate if you could help me here.

Comment: Could you show us the code for your main report? It could be that you are running the sub reports n times instead of once.

Answer (score 0):

I started to put this as a comment, but realized it is to much. This will not really answer your question but give you some troubleshooting steps to help find the problem.

1. Remove all the subreports from the master Report, and run preview to excel to make sure it works. If it does not work, try a completely blank report with just text to make sure it works, and if not, then I would uninstall and reinstall iReport.
2. Isolate each subreport and run preview to excel to make sure they work standalone. This may require some temporary changes to the report to allow them to run and not be dependent on the master report for data or parameters.
3. Add one subreport at a time back to the main report, checking the preview to excel to make sure it still works. If it stops working after adding a report you now found the trouble report. I would then remove all the reports that did not cause a problem and try it by it's self, just to make sure it is not a problem combining the reports together. If you can not figure it out, you should at least be able to form a more specific question here to get some help.
4. If you add all them all and it still works, congratulations you fixed it somehow. For some reason this usually ends up being the case for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when export in excel

My problem was that put page breaks in  my jrxml

When I tried to export in excel with no pagination i had the same error.

The Solution was put this condition in my page breaks:

```
        <break>
            <reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" x="0" y="106" width="100" height="1">
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[!$P{IS_IGNORE_PAGINATION}]]></printWhenExpression>
            </reportElement>
        </break>
```

Look printWhenExpression